# Get row from one table and insert it in other Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I`m trying to insert a row from one table to an other in Laravel 5.4 using an eloquent method, but I miss something. Can't figure it out ...

This is my code:

```
public function change($id)
{
   $car = Old::find($id);
   unset($car['created_at'],$car['updated_at']);
   $clone = $car->replicate();
   New::create($clone);
}
```

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type
>   array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an instance of your model, and you must pass an array so try this:

```
public function change($id)
{
   $car = Old::find($id);
   unset($car['created_at'],$car['updated_at']);
   $clone = $car->replicate();
   New::create($clone->toArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the one possible way

```
public function change($id)
{
 $car = Old::find($id);
 unset($car['created_at'],$car['updated_at']);
 $clone = $car->replicate();
 New::create(array($clone));
}
```

Or if you know the values you can create an array explicitly and create an entry in the `New Model`

```
New::create([
'name' => $clone->name,
'email => $clone->email,
...
]);
```

Comment: Yes, I know all the values. But it is more than 20. So idea was to make the code cleaner.